# What are the pros and cons of separating Entity Framework 6 Entities and POCO classes into individual class DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, class

I have a Wcf web service, and have both Entity Framework 6 model/entities, and my own POCO (business objects).

What are the pros and cons of separating the Entity Framework model and POCO classes into separate class DLLs ?

Comment: I wouldn't say there are any pros or cons. You put them in a separate project when you need them in multiple projects, just like you would with any other class you write.

Comment: Sounds like you figured it out already. Only tip I can give you is to use `EntityMapper` to configure the mapping to the database instead of Annotations, and you are sorted.